# Python Multiple version installation in Linux rocky

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I am new to Python and Linux env, so a little confused.
I want to find where my Python3.9 is installed, so that I can update the PATH..

- Running `python --version` or `python3 --version` give me ***Python 3.6.8***
- I want to install Python 3.9, so when I run `sudo dnf install -y  python39` it gives me
- ***Package python39-3.9.12-1ep1.el8.x86_64 is already installed.***
- `ls /usr/bin/python*` doesn't show 3.9
- Output of above command - ***/usr/bin/python  /usr/bin/python3  /usr/bin/python3.6
  /usr/bin/python3.6m***
- Also tried `alternatives --config python` but it shows only 3.6

  ```
    -----------------------------------------------
     *  1           /usr/libexec/no-python
      + 2           /usr/bin/python3
  ```
- `which python3.6` gives ***/usr/bin/python3.6***
- `which python3.9` gives ***/usr/bin/which: no python3.9 in....***
- `rpm -ql python39-3.9.12-1ep1.el8.x86_64` gives me
- ***/etc/gdbinit.d/python39.gdb. /opt/python3.9.
  /opt/python3.9/bin***

I could be missing something obvious, if someone can point me in the right direction it will be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the virtual machine I was working was built using vagrant, it had python 3.6 in usr/bin and python 3.9 in opt/python3.9. Newbie like me who wanna understand what /opt is - https://www.baeldung.com/linux/opt-directory

To search any package used [command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19369/how-to-find-the-installation-path-for-a-software-under-linux) - `rpm -ql python39-3.9.12-1ep1.el8.x86_64`

Once package is found add it to path as [symlinking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248029/how-should-executables-installed-under-opt-be-added-to-the-path) binaries can be confusing
`vim ~/.bashrc`
`PATH=/opt/python3.9/bin`

Answer (score 0):

what happens when you enter the following command: `python3 --version` and is it any different compared to running `python --version`?

Comment: Update the post as well... 
Same python3 --version
   Python 3.6.8

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your actual requirement is. But if you have already installed python 3.9 in your machine, then you can have this and all previous versions applied to different projects. This is selected when you create virtual environments. For example if you want to run a project that built on 3.6, then you can select python interpreter 3.6 at the time of creation.

Comment: I guess, my issue is I am not seeing the Python 3.9 anywhere but while installing it through dnf on AWS EC2 Linux rocky [if that helps], it says it is already installed.
I looked inside /usr/bin and I don't see 3.9